# Google App Script timeout errors frequently happens in a sheet with many editors

Tags: google-apps-script, timeout, runtime-error

I have a Google Sheet with a large dataset that is used in a scenario where multiple users (less than 10 individuals) can log in and edit it simultaneously, with a need for real-time synchronization. However, I've been encountering frequent timeout errors when calling this spreadsheet using automated processes through App Script recently. These errors are preventing the automation from running smoothly, even for basic data operations like setValues, setFormula, clearcontent, and so on.

I've sought assistance from Google Workspace customer support, and their response suggested that the timeout error is likely related to the scenario of multiple users editing the document simultaneously. In this context, how can I improve this situation?

Here is an example of the App Script code. I think mostly the error happens when code execution comes to "const main = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");"

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 
  const originalSheet = ss.getSheetByName('aaa');
  const modifySheet = ss.getSheetByName('bbb');
  const main = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  const mainSheet = main.getSheetByName("ABC");
  const mainSheetLastRow = glr(mainSheet,"A1:C");
  mainSheet.getRange(mainSheetLastRow + 2,1,moveRowNum,76).setValues(modifySheet.getRange(3,1,moveRowNum,76).getValues()); 
  
  mainSheet.getRange(mainSheetLastRow + 2,47 ,moveRowNum, 1).setFormula("=VLOOKUP($L:$L,'kkk'!$F$2:$N$3500,9,false)"); 
  mainSheet.getRange(mainSheetLastRow + 2,65 ,moveRowNum, 1).setFormula("=VLOOKUP($L:$L,'kkk'!$F$2:$J$3500,5,false)"); 

  originalSheet.getRange(3,1,moveRowNum,76).clearContent();
```

I have contacted Google Workspace customer support and was advised to look for help in this  community!

Comment: How is the function being executed?

Comment: It is executed manually in this large-dataset sheet itself or the other sheet by having the related functions in the onopen function. It could be easily clicked by a user on the sheet tool bar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're running with an onEdit trigger.  If so, it had better be an installable trigger  pointing to a handler function not named onEdit because the simple trigger of onEdit  cannot open files by id.  Also you should not use indeterminant ranges like "A1:C" within google apps scripts because you will get many nulls at bottom of the array.  And you should learn to take maximal advantage of the event object and quit wasting time calling functions for data that you already have.  Finally, the use SpreadsheetApp.flush is going to just make matters worse.  onEdit is  slow enough by itself without having to do a flush on every operation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not running with an onEdit trigger. But I could try to use close ranges in my code and not using SpreadsheetApp.flush to see if it could improve. I will feedback later.